# Replacing For Loop with either Map or Filter methods

Tags: javascript

Recently, I've had a task to complete and the task was the following:

**Write a function that gets two arguments:**

- First is an array of non-decreasing numbers
- The second is a single number

**The output of the function is a Boolean value. The output is “true” if in the passed array there are two
elements whose sum (+) is equal to the second argument. In all other cases, the output is “false”.**

So I've solved that problem with For Loops:

```
function checkSum(set, number) {

    for (let i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {

        for (let j = 1; j < set.length; j++) {

            if ((set[i] + set[j]) === number) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm just curious, is there any way to get rid of for loops and use either map or filter method.

Comment: Yes. Have you simply looked at the documentation for `.map()` and `.filter()`?

Comment: Sure! I just do not know how to check the summary with all the array members using Map or Filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any elements of the array match a given condition and [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find another element that can produce the given sum when added to the current element.

```
function checkSum(set, number){
    return set.some((x,idx)=>set.find((y,idx2)=>idx!==idx2&&x+y===number));
}
```

```js
function checkSum(set, number){
    return set.some((x,idx)=>set.find((y,idx2)=>idx!==idx2&&x+y===number));
}
console.log(checkSum([2,2,3], 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm seems to be wrong: it also accounts for the sum of an element with itself — except for the first element.
I.e.,

- `checkSum([1, 5], 10)` — returns `true`, but
- `checkSum([5, 100], 10)` — returns `false`.

Also, your algorithm is not optimized — it iterates over (almost) all pairs of elements. Since the array must be sorted, the algorithm can be optimized to only iterate over adjacent elements until the sum is greater than the given number.

You can easily implement the non-optimized of the algorithm using those "cool map/filter/find" methods, but the optimized version would probably be easier with the "old good loops".

Comment: Thanks for the attention. I will fix that.